# Powerquery list Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis

I have a very large table and certain columns have the rows packed into a list, how can I unpack all the lists of the column without losing the associations in Power BI Power query

for example:

""""

```
  column A      column B      column C

   List          List          List
```

and in the lists are even normal measured values and the date and time

as soon as I "expand" the columns to new rows I quarter the relationships

As a result I do not want to have the values in the list

```
Column A   Column B  ....   
1            5.7
1.2          4.3
1.4          6.7
2.4
```

Comment: Do you have sample data you can share and a desired result?

Comment: the formatting for the in the question is not correct, I have changed that now times

Comment: I want to display the measurement data later in a dashboard for this I do not want to have the values in a list for the time being but to have the values displayed:

Column A  Column B   ....
1                5.7       
1.2             4.3
1.4             6.7
2.4             ...

Answer (score -1):

by adding a custom column you can add all the columns to the new column by making it a new table. solved quite simply. Too bad that beginner but are not respected here and are immediately evaluated negatively!

Steps:

add custom column

```
     = Table.FromColumns({[columnA],[columnB],...})
```

then simply expand the table in the custom column